# 1998 Pontaic Firebird Base, what is causing a strange sound in 4th and 5th gears?

Tags: manual-transmission, pontiac, noise, firebird

I have a 1998 Firebird, base model with a 3.8L v6 engine with a 5 speed manual transmission. When I am driving faster than 50 mph in 4th, or 5th gear, I hear a hissing/humming sound from the direction of the glove department. What could be the case of this sound, and how would I go about to stop or reduce the sound in question?

Below is link leading to a google drive video that shows the sound in question.
I apologize that the quality of sound is not the greatest.

[Google drive video of sound.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FZq_psXRqmdFlVZWw1RGZnc2s/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can't hear anything in that vid. But take a look at wheel bearings. Is it drive line based? Lmk

Comment: Check the firewall on the right side, where the A/C fan and equipment is, this could just be air whistling through a gap and/or vibrating something when you get up to speed. Also, it could be tire noise...